# C# - place comments before or after class statement?

Tags: coding-style, comments

I've recently seen a system that uses a consistent placement of C# comments lexically preceding the commented item. For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// The pool of relative sequence ids used by the model.
/// Initially set to {1..Parameters.creditGoal}. Elements 
/// will be removed and put into the sequence window as credit
/// is acquired, and put back into the pool when they have been used. 
/// </summary>
static SetContainer<int> sequenceIdPool;
```

and

```
/// <summary>
/// Asserts a requirement with associated requirement description.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="condition"></param>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <param name="description"></param>
static void Requires(bool condition, int id, string description)
{
    Condition.IsTrue(condition, MakeRequirementId(id, description));
}
```

This seems strange and an obstacle to readability. I can't think of style for writing where subject identifiers (A-head, B-Head, etc.) precede details.

So, I'd rather see a comment block immediately follow the item it describes, e.g.,

```
static void Requires(bool condition, int id, string description)
/// <summary>
/// Asserts a requirement with associated requirement description.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="condition"></param>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <param name="description"></param>
{
    Condition.IsTrue(condition, MakeRequirementId(id, description));
}
```

Question: Is there any technical reason to favor placement of a comment block before its subject?

Answer (score 0):

Well, personally I have never seen any comment placed after target. As for me, it looks strange. Regarding technical reasons - for example, comments placed after target are not recognized by Visual Studio IntelliSense.